# Reverse required and optional properties

Tags: typescript

Let’s say I have the following type:

```
interface Foo {
  a?: string;
  b: string;
}
```

All properties can be made required using `Required`.

```
type Bar = Required<Foo>;

// Equivalent to
interface Bar {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

All properties can be made optional using `Partial`.

```
type Bar = Partial<Foo>;

// Equivalent to
interface Bar {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
}
```

I would like to make a generic type than flips the optional flag for all properties.

```
type Bar = Flip<Foo>;

// Equivalent to
interface Bar {
  a: string;
  b?: string;
}
```

The implementations for [`Partial`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b963e1a2a7e3b1056ee2552927fa08fcc51e4c7d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1421-L1426) and [`Required`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b963e1a2a7e3b1056ee2552927fa08fcc51e4c7d/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1428-L1433) are pretty straightforward, but this `Flip` type would need to know which properties of `Foo` are optional and which are required. Is is possible to read this modified using a generic?

Some context: I believe this would be a useful type for `defaultProps` in React.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your question as stated (where `Foo` has no [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)), you can define `Flip` (which I'll call `FlipOptional`) like this:

```
type OptionalKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type FlipOptional<T> = (Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeys<T>>> &
  Partial<Omit<T, OptionalKeys<T>>>) extends infer O
  ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }
  : never;
```

First we have to determine which keys of `T` are optional.  There's no simple built-in way to do this, but the above `OptionalKeys` type alias above works by checking which single-property widenings of `T` are [weak types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#weak-type-detection), as described in [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991061/2887218).  Index signatures mess this up, so if you need to operate on types with an index signature, you'll need something more complicated (which is also described in the linked answer).

Once you can figure out which keys are optional, it's relatively straightforward to construct an equivalent type to what you want, with [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) and [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) along with `Partial` and `Required` and an intersection: `Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeys<T>>> & Partial<Omit<T, OptionalKeys<T>>>`.  The only problem is that this type is relatively ugly; it would be nicer if the type were written out as a single object type.

Here I use a trick with [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) of the following form.  Say we have a type `Ugly` which consists of a lot of intersections and mappings. To make it pretty, we can do

```
type Pretty = Ugly extends infer O ? {[K in keyof O]: O[K]} : never
```

Here, `Ugly` is essentially "copied" to the `O` parameter, which is mapped over without changing anything.  This is mostly a no-op in terms of the output, but the result will be a single object type if possible.

---

Let's try it out:

```
interface Foo {
  a?: string;
  b: string;
}

type Bar = FlipOptional<Foo>;
/* type Bar = {
    a: string;
    b?: string | undefined;
} */

type FooAgain = FlipOptional<Bar>;
/* type FooAgain =  {
    b: string;
    a?: string | undefined;
} */

type MutuallyAssignable<T extends U, U extends V, V = T> = true;
type FooAgainIsFoo = MutuallyAssignable<Foo, FooAgain>; // okay
```

This all looks good.  `Bar` is what you expect, and `FlipOptional<Bar>` gives a type equivalent to `Foo`.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwNIRAZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCigG0soEUoBrXJAMyiIF0AtAH4AXNQC+UCAA9gEFABM8UAAoIAxu2IAaKFjLD9UcSggA3CACcaEhpxA8+-ANw0aoSFABiGBGDhEVExiMkoACgAlCABHAFcEKwhFAnUtXVh4ZHRsXEJSEjIAMjo1NCtEEJgAWwRgDMDszBx8UMKASmk5BWUWFG5rWFKjKkZmVg4uXhh+cRgmfigJUtMLazcaVnkrbjQNaG8kJGpStDEoPGArVgBzN3oAI3FL65Q723dPaAAhcoofPwBLLBDAEQ5IEhuAD0ACooF8oL8rP9aPR6Ghnldbvc0Q9zi9blAAD5QOJKCDcVjJNxSGFQz7gA5HACCNzQE0ovn8jRBBCRkJosPhjJ8LLZHPoqNxmNe7zRUDOMsJJLJigpVMUNKgdIZXgAsnFgHFMBgQMy8HgEDd0A8MBBiF15EoVABVPQux09FQANT03v+pH+VziEDcCPBrPZKAAknhwf8DUaTWaLVabXawUc9BHxShIVAoVCoEh2GgQDQgA)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a type system like this to construct `Flip<T>`:

```js
type OptionalPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never
}[keyof T];
type RequiredPropertyNames<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K
}[keyof T];
type OptionalProperties<T> = Pick<T, OptionalPropertyNames<T>>
type RequiredProperties<T> = Pick<T, RequiredPropertyNames<T>>

type Flip<T> = Partial<RequiredProperties<T>> & Required<OptionalProperties<T>>;


type Bar = Flip<X>;

// ==
interface Bar {
  a: string;
  b?: string | undefined;
}
```

See [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJwD8AXMgM5hSgDmA3PsgEZmXUj24C+uuYAngAcUAeUFhg6EHAA2ABSjphUAQDk4AWwjkAPABUAfMgC8ORgQDaAaWShkAawj90MZHoC6AWlLIAriAATCBhQCADkCAAPSEDyN2t3ZCJkGzIQCAA3aG4LR2dXDwYBYWQAJQgAR19gKDCFJWg1TW19I1M8AksbOzyXNy8ffyCQ9PComIC4vQSk5HSsqGQyKxzegvcioVFxSWl5RWUJFsMTZDlgBHt9ABpkMQkpWXrD-nUtXUMDPi2yyuragLPRrAY5tM4XK56W7lKo1OoHRqvZofAxfb4lVAyYCCVqnORwFTAWQ6GH-eENQmgowAMl+sIBOnuuyeCMpKIMDHRKEx2IATLj2uZkNZbCAHE4+h5vGQhsFQmNohBYvErIlktNVUsVYkAD5+QJy0YMLic4ooPTaMCnHk4jDoDlctyW3nWrGCfl2jlAA).

If you are ok with having `Flip` produce a type in which no property is optional, but instead the value as union with `undefined` you can it define like this:

```js
type Flip<X> = {
    [K in keyof X]-?: undefined extends X[K] ? X[K] : X[K] | undefined;
};
```

Which produces the following type in your example:

```js
type Bar = Flip<Foo>;

// Equivalent to
interface Bar {
  a: string;
  b: string | undefined;
}
```

Which should be sufficient in most cases and provides better autocompletion and "cleaner" types then the example above.

Explanation:

```js
[K in keyof X]-?:
```

this makes every property required. The next bit (conditional types) checks if the type was required and creates a union with `undefined` in that case - making it effectively optional:

```js
X[K] extends undefined ? X[K] : X[K] | undefined;
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/57593506/1154610 does exactly what I asked for.