# TypeScript: Get Optional Properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to create a new interface that contains only the optional fields of another interface?

```
declare interface TestInterface {
    mandatory: string,
    optional?: string,
}

declare interface OnlyOptional {
    optional: string
}

type OnlyOptionalExtended = GetOptional<TestInterface>;
```

I need my `OnlyOptional` and `OnlyOptionalExtended` interfaces to be exactly the same.

Comment: The syntax should be `type OnlyOptionalExtended = GetOptional<TestInterface>;`

Comment: Ok, but what I need here is the `GetOptional` type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a way to get all required properties of a typescript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984808/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-required-properties-of-a-typescript-object)