# Construct new type with required properties from the optional properties of another type

Tags: typescript

I have an interface consisting of an object with a set of properties:

```
interface Foo {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: number,
  prop3?: boolean,
  prop4?: object
}
```

Is there a way to construct a new type `Bar` that only contains the optional properties of `Foo`, but with each property being required like:

```
interface Bar {
  prop3: boolean,
  prop4: object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. First make note of the built in typescript helper types [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [`Required`](http://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype). Then you can build another helper type that will extract the optional keys of a type `T`:

```
type OptionalKeysOf<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Combine all of those:

```
type OnlyOptionalKeysToRequired<T> = Required<Pick<T, OptionalKeysOf<T>>>;
```

Then, when you use it:

```
type Bar = OnlyOptionalKeysToRequired<Foo>;

// Hovering that reveals:
// type Bar = {
//     prop3: boolean;
//     prop4: object;
// }
```

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqoAOMmRAjAFyoDOEM4A5gDQHGlEBM1YArgLYAjWK0IkyAZgD81QdgA2UBGFHsyAFhmpMggFZQkEYAF9gwCAE8iaAPJEIITGATyA0lAs0bcADwAVAD5UAF48NkIAbVdUcFQAaw9MOFQ-AF1qXjAAEyg4cCgs1CgAD2hsmhSo1NQpVGieKAA3WBMIhIsklNSAbjNLa1Q7BycXGgAlKABHXhAYAv8g0Inp2fmABRAkOP9mQftHZzcPL19AgIC%20qzQAIQQYEL3hw-GpmbmsnyxMAN6gA)

Comment: Note: your definition of `OptionalKeysOf<T>` doesn't really find optional properties; just ones that accept `undefined`.  So `{prop1: unknown}` would show up as `prop1` being an "optional" key.  You can use weak types to distinguish optional properties from ones that accept `undefined`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991061/2887218).

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I edited the answer to use your improved method. I was also wondering how to get it working with the new `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag, but your method even seems to handle that beautifully. Thanks again!