# Re-Mapping object keys with dot as nested objects with preserved value types

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to re-map object keys  `'prefix.suffix': value` as `{prefix: { suffix: value }}` but I struggle how to properly type the new re-mapped object.

How can I get my remappedData with nested object from keys that have a dot and preserve the value types?

```
export namespace LocationSchemas {
  export type BasicFields = {
    name: FieldProps;
    region: Region;
    types: Types;
    "alt.number"?: FieldProps;
    "alt.centreNumber"?: FieldProps;
    "typeDetails.available": TypeDetails;
    "typeDetails.virtual": TypeDetails;
    "internal.name"?: FieldProps;
    "internal.type": FieldProps;
    "internal.format"?: FieldProps;
    "internal.status": InternalTradingStatus;
  };

  export type FieldProps = {
    visible: boolean;
    editable: boolean;
  };

  export type PossibleValueAs<T> = {
    value: T;
  };
  export type PossibleValueAsString = PossibleValueAs<string>;
  export type PossibleValueAsStringArray = PossibleValueAs<string[]>;
  export type PossibleValueAsIso = PossibleValueAs<{
    isoCountryCode: string;
    isoSubdivision?: string;
  }>;

  export type Types = FieldProps & {
    possibleValues: PossibleValueAsStringArray[];
    defaultValue?: PossibleValueAsStringArray[];
  };

  export type TypeDetails = FieldProps & { defaultValue: boolean };

  export type Region = FieldProps & {
    possibleValues: PossibleValueAsIso[];
    defaultValue?: PossibleValueAsIso;
  };

  export type InternalTradingStatus = {
    visible: boolean;
    editable: boolean;
    possibleValues: PossibleValueAsString[];
  };
}

const remapKeys = (fields: LocationSchemas.BasicFields) => {
  return Object.entries(fields).reduce((base, currentValue) => {
    const [key, value] = currentValue;

    if (key.includes(".")) {
      const [firstHalf, secondHalf] = key.split(".");

      base[firstHalf] = { ...base[firstHalf], [secondHalf]: value };
    } else {
      base[key] = value;
    }

    return base;
  }, {});
};

const data: LocationSchemas.BasicFields = {
    name: {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
    },
    types: {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        possibleValues: [
            {
                value: ["Razor"],
            },
            {
                value: ["Deck"],
            },
        ],
    },
    region: {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        possibleValues: [
            {
                value: {
                    isoCountryCode: "GB",
                    isoSubdivision: "ENG",
                },
            },
            {
                value: {
                    isoCountryCode: "FR",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    "alt.number": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
    },
    "alt.centreNumber": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
    },
    
    "typeDetails.available": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    "typeDetails.virtual": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    "internal.name": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
    },
    "internal.type": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
    },
    "internal.status": {
        visible: true,
        editable: true,
        possibleValues: [
            {
                value: "TRADING",
            },
            {
                value: "UNKNOWN",
            },
        ],
    },
};



const remappedData = remapKeys(data) // I want object with re-mapped keys
```

Comment: Just it is clear what you want to do:  You'd like to take an arbitrary type with the naming convention, create a nested structure based on parsing the field names around the `.` (you seem to be OK with this as is), and then dynamically generate the correct typescript object types that represent them?

Comment: Is most of this code really germane to the question? I'm wondering why we need all the definitions of the property types instead of something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgGYbw).

Comment: (see prev comment) Assuming you're asking about how to write a utility type for a general one-level-deep mapping (e.g., dotted keys will only be at the top level) and assuming you don't care about type checking the *implementation* of your function (which will be impossible, TS isn't that smart), then maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY2bEw) meets your needs? Deeply recursive type functions tend to have weird edge cases so you might want to test thoroughly to be sure. If it meets your needs then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I agree most of types are not necessary but I always tend to try to give comprehensive example so it can be understood better by others. Anyway, your approach with the utility is what I was looking for. I greatly appreciate and yes please if you could give an answer with explanation i will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're mostly looking to write a utility type called `RemapKeys<T>` which will be the desired output type for the `remapKeys()` function given an input of type `T`.  I'm not going to worry about the implementation of `remapKeys()` or how to convince the compiler that the implementation matches the type; you'll need to just check the implementation yourself, and use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that the values it returns are of that type.

Note that such deeply [recursive types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) tend to have bizarre edge cases, especially if it's not completely specified in advance what you want the behavior to be.  And if turns out that some edge case behavior is unacceptable, you might find that the type needs a complete refactoring, and not a slight tweak.  So be sure to test recursive types like this thoroughly against expected use cases.

---

The general approach I will take for `RemapKeys<T>` is to

- for each property `K` with value `V`, produce a "nested `Record` type", `NestedRecord<K, V>`, which is like [the `Record<K, V>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) except that each dot inside `K` causes it to be nested deeper.  So for the property `{"a.b.c": string}`, it will produce the type `{a: {b: {c: string}}}`;
- combine these nested records together into a single object, by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) them; and,
- collapse this big intersection into a single object type for ease of display and understanding.

---

First we need `NestedRecord<K, V>`. The basic version of this is

```
type NestedRecord<K extends PropertyKey, V> =
  K extends `${infer K0}.${infer KR}` ?
    { [P in K0]: NestedRecord<KR, V> } :
    { [P in K]: V }
```

which turns `{"a.b.c":0}` into `{a:{b:{c:0}}}`.  But it doesn't preserve [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties).  I assume you want `{"a.b.c"?: string}` to turn into `{a?: {b?: {c?: string}}}` where each part of the structure is optional. This might not completely represent the truth, since you would either have `{a: {b: {c: string}}}` or `{}`, and probably don't want to support "partially" present paths like `{a: {b: {}}`, but it might be close enough.  Furthermore, I will assume that a property is optional if [`undefined`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) is assignable to it.  This isn't strictly the same thing, and if you want something exact you can look at [is there a way to get all required properties of a typescript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52984808/2887218), but again, this is probably close enough.  Thus a version that also works with optionals is

```
type NestedRecord<K extends PropertyKey, V> =
  K extends `${infer K0}.${infer KR}` ?
  undefined extends V ? { [P in K0]?: NestedRecord<KR, V> } : { [P in K0]: NestedRecord<KR, V> } :
  undefined extends V ? { [P in K]?: V } : { [P in K]: V }
```

---

Now we need to combine all these nested records into a single object. Conceptually you'd get that by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) them all together, so `{"a.b": string, "c.d": string}` would become something like `{a:{b:string}} & {c:{d:string}}`.  We can do that by making use of a technique similar to `UnionToIntersection` as described in  [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218).  Like this:

```
type RemapKeys<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]: (x: NestedRecord<K, T[K]>) => void } extends
  Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never;
```

Essentially what I'm doing is converting these nested records as parameters of a function type, and then using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to infer a single type from that position.  This results in an intersection instead of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

---

Finally, we want to collapse that together to a single object type, so that `{a:{b:string}} & {c:{d:string}}` becomes `{a: {b: string}; c: {d: string}}`.  For this I'll use a utility type `ExpandRecursively<T>`, which recursively [maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) the properties of an object type to themselves.  This is described at [How can I see the full expanded contract of a Typescript type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57683303/2887218) and looks like:

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> =
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: ExpandRecursively<T[K]> } : T;
```

So putting that together gives us

```
type RemapKeys<T extends object> = ExpandRecursively<
  { [K in keyof T]: (x: NestedRecord<K, T[K]>) => void } extends
  Record<string, (x: infer I) => void> ? I : never
>;
```

---

Okay, let's test it out.  We start with

```
type BasicFields = {
  name: FieldProps;
  region: Region;
  types: Types;
  "alt.number"?: FieldProps;
  "alt.centreNumber"?: FieldProps;
  "typeDetails.available": TypeDetails;
  "typeDetails.virtual": TypeDetails;
  "internal.name"?: FieldProps;
  "internal.type": FieldProps;
  "internal.format"?: FieldProps;
  "internal.status": InternalTradingStatus;
};
```

and then use `RemapKeys` on it, which gives us a type equivalent to the following:

```
type RemappedFields = RemapKeys<BasicFields>
/* type RemappedFields = {
    name: FieldProps;
    region: Region;
    types: Types;
    alt?: {
        number?: FieldProps;
        centreNumber?: FieldProps;
    };
    typeDetails: {
        available: TypeDetails;
        virtual: TypeDetails;
    };
    internal: {
        name?: FieldProps;
        type: FieldProps;
        format?: FieldProps;
        status: InternalTradingStatus;
    };
} */
```

That looks like what you want.  Note that the `alt` property is optional because both of its subproperties are also optional, but `internal` is required because at least some of its subproperties are required.  This falls out naturally when combining intersections; a property which is required in any member of an intersection becomes required in the result.

---

So there's the basic approach I'm using.  There are certainly other ways to do it, and depending on edge cases and use cases there might be better ways to do it.  Check thoroughly and make changes if needed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false#code/FAFwngDgpgBAclAziKATASlAxgewE6oA8A0jFAB4oB2qiMACnjtHuMVGADQwBqAfDAC8wGDFIVqtGAAMAJAG8AllQBmUPGIAMAXwB0C5Wo3F026TAD8ImAFcaUFcrRlKUGnR6WY8mAG16MMpaALoWAFzwSCgY2PhEJtz8MNowET7+gVQhEQjIaJi4BCToiQIpYdZ2qA5OqC6SHl7pAUHEoRGe5d5+LVltHcnAoJCwAKLkEACGNAU2eIiKAG5QADZghAAqAsKiG-VuUjgARgBW2CBNfqRBANYcOCowG8ER41Mz2HMLy2ubvm1lVJPADcQ3A0BgmAAtpMIOwwIhNvt3DBjmcsCBtjA3tMYlgvktVutrOlrlk7mAHk8XjAABTkHJRfKxIrEbgbf7BPgASiEAkWOEUdRSEgOiGsBTihGQeGUAHNuPSIoZ1DAAJK8wT8wWoAQWdVAqhQZZ4YB8UHAZQoPAqSZYWAAMUUq1QjGYdB8KgimkGVvUtvtkKgcsUOCyPjw3t9VGtAdgGxGHpgICj2ktMf9dvjIwAIlAQJNFCskymYABGaOxrPqjN4KiTFYbPCTVDygDKBZANiTilTYJGMAAQpMFlgnS66IJvNZ61CoBFxytXUwIIhQaI8MHQ1QIpgQ2H18nExEE9A19YAEQNkC6Kg2KFHdQX8IwRfL92Hq8rG-2mObuD3o+eDPguzpLm6q6fuCUB5gWRaILokyLIWKyTEcKxQBeJ65vmKHnqIF7QbBeG6IsiisDYDZYU8OFwcWn5+nWDa3pMc4ga+YHvpBl6MfWKy6NB1FvhB+EwBevHMSo+AwiA7HCSuonibWfG6Mgkxdog1FqspDZNi27adt2oLaBa0FBjCEDQKgb6TuZsLwoiw6jjZfDAAA9AAVEeELQrCVk2UI06iKIs7zhxLoiYeG5bmGu4xVQUXeUg2Fnol14vvI1jBcFd4PuoL7ye6MAAD62PYjhGqgiXZb+ID-oB+WgRFCklWV1QVWgiUpKVVQ1JViVEbh8FpFl2UwEhKFoRhKUwUN9GjdlZEUQ2M3EfBXWJRJKwjWNOWsVABWcSJrW9R1VULcF0FNeBCnVcFUl4DJh3NUVPXlbUd2iGpGkRNp1p8XprZUHKHbqUZo0mcAKQeW5wBAA)