# typescript i want a type for a variable that is equal to an array of the interface properties

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript

I have this User

```
interface User { 
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  age?: number;
}
```

I have this inline code

```
const requiredFields: Array<keyof User> = ['firstName', 'lastName'];
```

now I don't get an error but the requiredFields type is not correct because in the User interface the email is also required so what the type of the requiredFields should be to make sure all required properties included in the array?

Comment: This is really two questions in the sense that there are two conceptual pieces to it.  One: "get the list of required properties", which is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52984808/2887218.  Two: "make sure an array contains at least one element of each of its element type union members" a.k.a an "exhaustive array", which is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55265679/2887218.  Am I missing anything else about the question?

Answer (score 0):

Define a utility type to extract required keys:

```
type RequiredKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: {} extends Pick<T, K> ? never : K
}[keyof T];
```

Use this utility type with your User interface:

```
interface User { 
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  age?: number;
}

// Example usage of RequiredKeys to get only required keys
type UserRequiredKeys = RequiredKeys<User>;
```

Comment: This doesn't touch the "exhaustive array" part of the question.